# Characters changing in Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a dll written in C#.  One of the methods takes a parameter `string txt`.  The dll is being called from a classic asp page.  At the time of calling, the text contains the character `é` which is obtained by holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and typing 130 on the number pad or by holding down <kbd>ALT-GR</kbd> and hitting <kbd>e</kbd>.

The [DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) method is outputting it wrong.  I realize there is a character set/font issue, but I don't know how to get round the problem.

What I get on a British keyboard and localization using Arial font is a capital A with a tilde above it followed by lowercase c in a circle.

The individual entering the text may be using any keyboard layout, may have any localization on their PC, but they will all be entering it via our web page.

What do I need to do to make things compatible or to convert?

The relevant bit of code is:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(strFilePath);

Graphics m_graphics;
m_graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

Font fnt = new Font("Arial", 12.0f);

StringFormat strFormatter = new StringFormat();

SolidBrush txtBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(127, Color.FromArgb(int.Parse("AB12CD", NumberStyles.HexNumber))));

m_graphics.DrawString("é", fnt, txtBrush, new Point(200, 200), strFormatter);
```

Comment: Hi, can you show what output you are getting, as well as a snippet of your actual code calling draw string.  Without this information your question will likely be closed.

Comment: It sounds like an encoding issue...

Comment: I've added the relevant code and the output I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your string of text is coming from a web page, it could be URL encoded.
Try decoding it first, and making sure the result is UTF8:

```
string strDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strEncoded, Encoding.UTF8)

m_graphics.DrawString(strEncoded, fnt, txtBrush, new Point(200, 200), strFormatter);
```

Comment: The namespace that HttpUtility is in, is not available inside a dll

Comment: But Uri.UnescapeDataString is available and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

`é` is encoded as [`U+00E9`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) in Unicode, which results in UTF-8 `0xC3 0xA9`.

`U+00C3` is `Ã`, and `U+00A9` is `©` ([source](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=0x)).

So you clearly have an encoding problem, and the relevant code is not the one you posted, but the code that receives the string from the web request and passes it through the page (code-behind?) into your DLL.

Comment: So how do I change a passed string from one encoding to another.  The web site is using utf-8.  How do I find out what the dll is using or better still, how do I set it?